# Threads stops at Beautifulsoup command - unable to interrupt

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a python code to scrape a blog that looks a bit like this:

```
def main():
    thread=threading.Thread(target=blogthread,args=(path,username))
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
    ...

def blogthread(path,username,steem):
    s=site_scraper.userposts(username)
    ...

def userposts(username):
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(url,timeout=200)   
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f,'html.parser')  
    ...
```

If I call userposts(username) directly, it works just fine. When threads are involved, my main() finishes, but every other thread gets stuck exactly at the "Beautifulsoup" line. It never continues, even when the main thread is done.

By playing with the code, I've notice that if I add an error at the end of the main thread (like an undefined variable), I get an error message, but my threads suddenly start to pick up again and output the required results.

I'm really confused, thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

The main thread finishes but the other threads are still running. I don't know why they get stuck at the BeautifulSoup line. However, you can fix it by exiting the program if the main thread is done. Simply do a `sys.exit()` command at the end of the main thread.